# How to prevent a Flash-based MP3 player from playing files hosted in external domains?

Tags: apache, http, url, flash

I'm using [1PixelOut](http://typo3.org/extensions/repository/view/onepixelout) as a flash MP3 player in my website. 
However I discovered that by pointing the browser directly to the swf file in my website (e.g. www.myurl.com/player.swf) and passing an external URL through the get parameter *soundFile=* everyone can use the player to play external mp3 files (i.e. not hosted in my domain) without any warning nor limitation.

I don't have the source of the flash player, since it comes pre-compiled. I tried with other swf players (e.g. podango) and the behaviour is the same: they can play cross domain located mp3 files. Hence, I believe this issue is related to the flash player plugin.

When in try locally (i.e. in my laptop) to point the browser to the swf file location and try to pass the *soundFile* parameter, I receive the following security warning (which is what I would expect):
[image: Javascript alert when I try to play an external MP3]

**However**, if I start a local server in my laptop (MAMP, in my case) and point to the exact same location as before with the browser, but using the localhost server url (*localhost:8888/* instead of *file:///*), I don't get any notice nor warning and I can play the remote mp3 file passed via URL get directly to the swf file:
[image: Playing an remotely hosted mp3 file without any warning].
This is the same behaviour I get in my website.

I don't understand, why this difference in flash player behaviour in my local host?

How can I prevent the second situation to happen without having to tweak the server configuration (e.g. .htaccess)?

I don't think is normal that if you have an .swf mp3 player on your server, everyone could potentially use it to play files outside the domain where the player is hosted: this is a potential security issue (many scripts on the web use the same flash player)